# toString() equivalent in OCaml

Tags: ocaml

I am new to OCaml and trying to debug some OCaml code.
Is there any function in OCaml equivalent to `toString()` function in Java by which most of the objects can be printed as output?

Comment: It has been an Achilles-feet of OCaml. The answer will probably depend on whether you use *Core* or *Batteries*.

Answer (score 11):

There are functions like string_of_int, string_of_float, string_of_bool in the Pervasives module (you don't have to open the Pervasives module because it's... pervasive).

Alternatively, you can use Printf to do this kind of output.  For example:

```
let str = "bar" in
let num = 1 in
let flt = 3.14159 in
Printf.printf "The string is: %s, num is: %d, float is: %f" str num flt
```

There's also a sprintf function in the Printf module, so if you wanted to just create a string instead of printing to stdout you could replace that last line with:

```
let output = Printf.sprintf "The string is: %s, num is: %d, float is: %f" str num flt
```

For more complex datatypes of your own definition, you could use the [Deriving](https://code.google.com/p/deriving/wiki/Introduction) extension so that you woudn't need to define your own pretty-printer functions for your type.

Comment: Sexplib library can be useful too.

Answer (score 6):

If you use Core and the associated Sexplib syntax extension, there are pretty good solutions to this.  Essentially, sexplib auto-generates converters from OCaml types to and from s-expressions, providing a convenient serialization format.

Here's an example using Core and Utop.  Make sure you follow the following instructions for getting yourself set up to use Core: http://realworldocaml.org/install

```
utop[12]> type foo = { x: int
                     ; y: string
                     ; z: (int * int) list
                     }
          with sexp;;

type foo = { x : int; y : string; z : (int * int) list; }
val foo_of_sexp : Sexp.t -> foo = <fun>
val sexp_of_foo : foo -> Sexp.t = <fun>
utop[13]> let thing = { x = 3; y = "hello"; z = [1,1; 2,3; 4,2] } ;;
val thing : foo = {x = 3; y = "hello"; z = [(1, 1); (2, 3); (4, 2)]}
utop[14]> sexp_of_foo thing;;
- : Sexp.t = ((x 3) (y hello) (z ((1 1) (2 3) (4 2))))
utop[15]> sexp_of_foo thing |> Sexp.to_string_hum;;
- : string = "((x 3) (y hello) (z ((1 1) (2 3) (4 2))))"
```

You can also generate sexp-converters for un-named types, using the following inline quotation syntax.

```
utop[18]> (<:sexp_of<int * float list>> (3,[4.;5.;6.]));;
- : Sexp.t = (3 (4 5 6))
```

More detail is available here: https://realworldocaml.org/v1/en/html/data-serialization-with-s-expressions.html